# Debug Assertion Error - OpenCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I am testing this code for practical purposes: [Number Plate](https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code/tree/master/Chapter5_NumberPlateRecognition).

This program is running on my friend's machine but it is giving a

> Debug Assertion Error!
>
> is_block_type_valid(_header->block_use)

When does this error come? Can someone throw a pointer or two? I can't find any help on the internet. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

I think this happens if you deallocate memory which was not allocated or already was deallocated when using debug heap on windows.